# How can I normalise sort order of hypens between machines?

Tags: c#, .net, sorting, locale

I have a **Windows 2019** server (set to **en-US** for all language settings) for which the following code:

```
var unsorted = new[] {"Aldi", "Al-Murad Tiles", "AliExpress" };
Console.WriteLine("Unsorted: " + string.Join(',', unsorted));
var sorted = unsorted.OrderBy(x => x);
Console.WriteLine("Sorted: " + string.Join(',', sorted));
```

Produces:

[image]

I have a **Windows 11** machine (set to **en-GB** for all language settings) for which the same code produces:

[image]

It makes no difference if I set the culture of the current thread to be the same as the server:

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
```

Does anyone know what settings should be applied to the current thread to make existing code sort the same on the Windows 11 machine as it does on the server?

*(worth saying this is an example extracted from a much larger legacy codebase so I'd like to make minimal code changes to the affect the current thread/context/environment to make this sorting work rather than re-factor the existing code)*

Comment: Do the machines happen to have different version of .NET?

Comment: If so, it might be because of [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/globalization/5.0/icu-globalization-api).

Comment: Ahh yes, I think you have something there... I did as they suggest in that article and use `StringComparer.Ordinal` and it then works the same way on both (however, it's the Windows 11 way with the hyphen at the start - so, broken as it may be, I'd like to change the environment of the Windows 11 machine to make it sort like the server if possible - maybe it's not without installing a different version of the OS - I **think** this wasn't a problem with Windows 10)

Comment: You can configure .NET to still use NLS: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/runtime-config/globalization#nls

Comment: Perfect! adding the following to **runtimeconfig.json** : `"configProperties": { "System.Globalization.UseNls": "true" }`  is the answer

Comment: But ICU is used also outside WIndows, so probably you should use ICU anyway (and if you are doing good internationalization, better to use directly ICU libraries)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In .NET 5, [Globalisation APIs now use ICU libraries, rather than NLS, on Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/globalization/5.0/icu-globalization-api), so if one of your machines is running on .NET 5, and the other is running an earlier version, then this could explain why changing the current's thread's culture info doesn't help at all.

You can use an `Ordinal` comparison:

```
var sorted = unsorted.OrderBy(x => x, StringComparer.Ordinal);
```

Alternatively, you can also [make your .NET 5 app use NLS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/runtime-config/globalization#nls) by editing runtimeconfig.json

```
"configProperties": { "System.Globalization.UseNls": "true" }
```

Or setting the `DOTNET_SYSTEM_GLOBALIZATION_USENLS` environment variable.

Comment: Also... to get that setting to appear in your runtimeconfig.json, you can add `<ItemGroup><RuntimeHostConfigurationOption Include="System.Globalization.UseNls" Value="true" /></ItemGroup>` to your **.csproj** as per [this](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/43736#issuecomment-754847733)